# Намеренное переполнение буфера

Tags: linux, c, ubuntu, взлом

Я изучаю элементарное переполнение буфера и внедрение шеллкода. У меня есть небольшая проблема...

Программа:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   char buffer[24];

   strcpy(buffer, argv[1]);

   return 0;
}
```

Компилировал так:

> `gcc -ggdb -z execstack -fno-stack-protector simple_overflow.c`

Переполнял по стандарту: nop-шелл-возврат, а именно: `\x90*13 + shellcode(/bin/sh) + \x28\xf1\xff\xbf`

Буфер переполняется, nop-команды пропускаются и выполняются две инструкции: `xor  eax, eax` и `push  eax`:

```
0xbffff135: xor  eax,eax
0xbffff137: push eax
0xbffff138: push 0x68732f2f
0xbffff13d: push 0x6e69622f
0xbffff142: mov  ebx,esp
0xbffff144: push eax
0xbffff145: push ebx
0xbffff146: mov  ecx,esp
0xbffff148: mov  al,0xb
0xbffff14a: int  0x80
```

Но после выполнения третьей команды (вносящей в стек строку `hs//`), строки, отвечающие за вызов `execve()`, заменяются двумя командами `das`:

```
0xbffff13d: push  0x6e69622f
0xbffff142: mov   ebx,esp
0xbffff144: push  eax
0xbffff145: push  ebx
0xbffff146: mov   ecx,esp
0xbffff148: das    
0xbffff149: das
```

...выполнение `execve()` не происходит.
Что я делаю не так?

Comment: попробуй заменить `return 0` на  `execve ("/bin/ls",argv, {NULL}); `